# GCM Registration ID Lifetime - Can GCM change the ID, how do you alert the phone

Tags: java, android, push, registration, google-cloud-messaging

I've read all the docs and have implemented Push on Android but I'm a bit confused as to the lifetime of the registration ID.

Will GCM invalid or change the key after a period of time and how do you keep the GCM registered device aware of its new ID (so it can sync its new ID to my server).

Its probably out of context but I am worried because I keep seeing comments like these:

"Note that Google may periodically refresh the registration ID"

(See https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/ - Admittedly from old c2dm instead of GCM but I still want to be sure.)

(See Also [Should applications call gcm.register() every seven days to ensure valid registration IDs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17891399/should-applications-call-gcm-register-every-seven-days-to-ensure-valid-registr))

Comment: See the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629764/. Basically you need to check the response on your server for a canonical_id

Comment: I see. However the nature of the registration with my push server means that the phone also has to know at all times whether it's ID is correct.

Having said you have answered my original question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handling registration ID changes in Google Cloud Messaging on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16838654/handling-registration-id-changes-in-google-cloud-messaging-on-android)